# Is there a documentation or a tutorial for integrating passport.js into sails.js?

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

Every tutorial or unfinished documentation out there doensn't work. This is why I ask here: Is there a simple tutorial, which really works, for passport and sails?

Comment: http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/
this is nice tutorial!!!

Comment: Maybe you need to read the reference documentation and write the code yourself and not look for a "tutorial"

Comment: maybe... but maybe the documentation is not finished or doesn't work. Have you tried it? Did it really work? Post the URL, I'll read that and try it - and when something doesn't work, I'll ask you. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

follow this steps two integrate passport with sails js 
first :- 
List these dependencies inside application_directory/package.json  under dependencies
//application_directory/package.json

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "passport": "~0.1.16",
    "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
    "bcrypt": "~0.7.6"
  }
...
}
```

**2-**
To create user model run the following command:

```
sails generate model user
```

3- model user.js  will look like  the following

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }
  },

  beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          cb(err);
        }else{
          user.password = hash;
          cb(null, user);
        }
      });
    });
  }

};
```

**4**-  To create a controller in sails type the command

```
sails generate controller
```

AuthController will look like the following:

```
var passport = require('passport');
module.exports = {

  login: function (req, res) {
    res.view();
  },
  process: function(req, res){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        return res.send({
        message: 'login failed'
        });
        res.send(err);
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        return res.send({
          message: 'login successful'
        });
      });
    })(req, res);
  },
  logout: function (req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.send('logout successful');
  }
};

module.exports.blueprints = {
  actions: true,
  rest: true,

  shortcuts: true

};
```

**5**- add the following code to application_directory/config/routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
  // (This would also work if you had a file at: `/views/home.ejs`)
  '/': {
    view: 'home/index'
  },

  '/login': {
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'login'
  },
  '/logout': {
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'logout'
  }
  ......
}
```

**6**- Inside application_directory/config create a file passport.js and add the following code to that

```
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
module.exports = {
  express: {
    customMiddleware: function(app){
      console.log('Express midleware for passport');
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());
    }
  }
};
```

**7**- Inside /api/services/ create a file passport.js and add the following code to that

```
var passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); &lt; /code&gt;
//helper functions
function findById(id, fn) {
  User.findOne(id).done(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return fn(null, null);
    } else {
      return fn(null, user);
    }
  });
}

function findByUsername(u, fn) {
  User.findOne({
    username: u
  }).done(function (err, user) {
    // Error handling
    if (err) {
      return fn(null, null);
      // The User was found successfully!
    } else {
      return fn(null, user);
    }
  });
}

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      findByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
        if (err)
          return done(null, err);
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Unknown user ' + username
          });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
          if (!res)
            return done(null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Password'
            });
          var returnUser = {
            username: user.username,
            createdAt: user.createdAt,
            id: user.id
          };
          return done(null, returnUser, {
            message: 'Logged In Successfully'
          });
        });
      })
    });
  }
));
```

**8**- Modify the authenticated.js file present inside /api/policies/

```
/**
 * Allow any authenticated user.
 */

    module.exports = function (req, res, ok) {

      // User is allowed, proceed to controller

          var is_auth = req.isAuthenticated()
          if (is_auth) return next();
          // User is not allowed
          else return res.redirect("/login");
        };
```

Comment: thx Ahmed, where does this "isAuthenticated()" in the last snipped come from? I have in the bcrypt.compare() function also returned the userrole (isAdmin) in the "var returnUser" - how can I write a policy for that? how can I check if the loged in user is Admin or not?

Comment: Ok I found it.  
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { console.log(req.user.isAdmin);}